# Android project.properties access is denied on windows during android update project

Tags: android, ant

I have checked permissions but I still get this error when running

android update project --target android-17 -p . --subprojects

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a rare problem, but the solution is simple.

After I had downloaded the latest version of the application from our TFS, some files had the **Read-only** property, and I simply unchecked it.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/prevent-changes-to-a-file-by-setting-it-to-read-only

[image: The Read-only check box]

---

**On Linux**

You must have the Write permissions to modify `project.properties`